# Eclipse Neon preferences has duplicated Android entry

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-neon

Android menu preferences in my eclipse neon are duplicated and I don't know which instance is actually active.
See image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely caused because you have Eclipse for Android Developers (including the Andmore project, which contributes one of those sets of preferences) and Google ADT plugins installed in it (contributing the other set).

As Google ADT is not maintained, I would recommend to stick with Andmore and uninstall ADT.